# Exibir um vídeo diferente para cada visitante

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

Estou fazendo uma página HTML com JavaScript e gostaria que para cada usuário que a visite o vídeo inicial seja alterado.

Eu tenho 5 vídeos, então no primeiro acesso o vídeo 1 seria exibido, depois o vídeo 2 e assim por diante, até que no sexto acesso voltaria a exibir o vídeo 1.

É possível fazer isso? Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonathan, no caso específico do PHP, você vai ter que armazenar essa contagem em algum lugar, porque depois que processo do PHP do encerra, todas as informações são perdidas.

No caso eu vou usar [Redis](https://redis.io). Redis é um banco de dados na memória, muito rápido e pequeno, ideal para esse tipo de coisa.

Se tiver usando windows é só [baixar os binários](https://github.com/dmajkic/redis/downloads) e executar o arquivo *redis-server*. E instalar a [extensão](https://pecl.php.net/package/redis/).

```
<?php
// pegos os videos na pasta atual
$videos = glob('./*.mp4');


$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1');

/* se não existir uma chave chamada 'nacessos',
ele cria e retorna 1, se existir ele incrementa
e retorna o valor
*/
$nacessos = $redis->incr('nacessos');

$video = $videos[$nacessos % count($videos)];
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf8">
</head>

<body>

<h1 id="titulo"><?= $video ?>, acesso #<?= $nacessos ?></h1>
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls autoplay muted loop>
  <source src="<?= $video ?>" type="video/mp4">
  <p>Seu navegador não suporta o vídeo.</p>
</video>

</body>
</html>
<?php
```

Answer (score 2):

Claro, é pra isso que servem os "Cookies": https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Pequei parte do código em https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Você só precisa criar um cookie com o número de acessos e então ficar pegando o resto da divisão do número de acessos pela quantidade de vídeos. E assim você vai saber qual o vídeo que vai exibir.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf8">
<script>
// Você pode por o nome que quiser dos vídeos, e quantidade que quiser
var videos = ["v1.mp4", "v2.mp4", "v3.mp4"];

function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var acessos = getCookie("acessos");
    if (acessos != "") {
        acessos = parseInt(acessos)+1;
    } else {
        // Caso queria que sempre seja visto primeiro
        // o primeiro vídeo, descomente a próxima linha
        //var acessos = 1;

        // Ou gerando o priemiro vídeo aletatório, se baseando
        // no tamanho do array vídeos
        acessos = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
    }
    setCookie("acessos", acessos, 30);
    setVideo(acessos);
}

function setVideo(acessos) {
    var video = videos[acessos % videos.length];
    document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = video;

    var src = document.createElement("source");
    src.setAttribute("src", video);
    src.setAttribute("type","video/mp4");
    var video = document.getElementById("video");
    video.appendChild(src);
    video.play();
}


</script>
</head>

<body onload="checkCookie()">

<h1 id="titulo"></h1>
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" loop controls>
  <p>Seu navegador não suporta o vídeo.</p>
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PRIMEIRAMENTE O MEU MUITO OBRIGADO PELA ATENÇÃO.

Poxa  acho que fiz alguma coisa errada porque não aparece o vídeo
o titulo muda certinho, eu adicionei os videos lá tudo com os nome v1, v2, v3, v4 e v5 todos em MP4. mas não rodou os vídeo, e mesmo que fosse outro usuário  ele deveria seguir a contagem do usuário anterior segue o link:

https://testewww.000webhostapp.com/teste-nathan/index.html

Comment: O erro foi meu, já já corrigo isso. Agora, se você quer que pra cada usuário que acesse o site mude o vídeo, vc vai ter que armazenar o número de acessos no servidor. Mas na verdade isso não ser muito diferente de escolher aleatoriamente um vídeo, do ponto de vista do usuário.

Comment: Novamente agradeço, pela atenção e sem querer abusar muito de sua boa vontade, tem algum tópico ou link que me ajude nesse ponto que para mim é importante que eles sigam a ordem através de outros usuários também 
Exemplo usuário a entrar e assisti ou está assistindo o v1.mp4  o próximo a acessar usuário b mesmo de outro dispositivo vai entrar vai assistir o v2.mp4 e assim por diante.

Comment: Bem, agora vai mostrar os vídeos. Agora, o que você está usando do lado do servidor? PHP? Python? Node.js? Para eu colocar o exemplo específico do vídeo pelo usuário.

Comment: Eu uso PHP, aqui no servidor

Comment: Então acabei vendo que dessa forma funcionar, porém para exatamente o que eu quero não conseguir aplicar bem. Então o que acontece. que eu vou usar esse html, (para dentro de uma RB ) e criar um hotspot, e a cada vez que alguém entrasse nesse wifi antes de liberar a internet iria apresenta um vídeo e o mesmo seguir em esquecia, para os clientes que se conectarem em posterior, na minha lojinha. Na minha cabeça teria como esse html tipo gerar um txt dentro da pasta que o mesmo fica dentro do roteador e desse txt ele manda e buscar o valor para soltar os videos.